# How to move element with position on every click Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a button

```
        <button class="item">Button</button>
```

And I want it to move 100px left everytime I click on it
So I did this

```js
item = document.querySelector(".item")
let moveItem =()=>{
   item.style.position = 'absolute'
   item.style.left += '100px'
}

item.addEventListener("click", moveItem)
```

But it only moves one time.
How do i move it everytime i click on it?

Answer (score 0):

Logical error in generating the position left value

Adding position left like `item.style.left += '100px'` will keeps on generating a string consisting of `100px` multiple times. First time it runs, it will gives you a result `100px` which you sets for the position left, next time this operation will give you a result `100px100px` which is an invalid value for position left. So it will not update the position left property with the new value, instead it keeps the old value.

**My solution:** Each time you click the button, get the current numeric value for the position left and 100 to that value.

```js
item = document.querySelector(".item")
let moveItem =()=>{
   item.style.position = 'absolute'
   const currentpos = item.style.left.match(/\d+/g);
   item.style.left = currentpos ? +currentpos[0] + 100 + 'px' : '100px'
}
item.addEventListener("click", moveItem)
```

```html
<button class="item">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First your brackets are wrong on your `moveItem` function so change these to curly braces, then `style.left` returns null or a string so you need to parse it as an int:

```js
const item = document.querySelector(".item")
let moveItem = () => {                       // change bracket type
   item.style.position = 'absolute';
   
   const left =  item.style.left || 0;       // get left if it exists or default to zero
   
   item.style.left = `${parseInt(left, 10) + 100}px`;   // change the left value to an int and add 100 
}

item.addEventListener("click", moveItem)
```

```html
<button class="item">Button</button>
```